# Opencart 2.3.0.2: additional column in product list using multi user extension

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, opencart

Sorry. I am very new in opencart template which include model-view-controller-language. In my project is want to create multi user seller using opencart version 2.3.0.2. But opencart provide for 1 seller only. Therefore i use extension available which is [dream multiuser](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=25455).

After installation, i could see changes in my database user which add new column name user_id.[image: table user]

In admin catalog->product dashboard, there are some additional column which is user_id.[image]

1. Is that possible to rename the user_id column with seller name and shown the firstname attribute? if user_id=1, shown firstname alvin for example. Make more userfriendly. Easy readable seller name instead of id.
2. How to add user id/seller name filter column in filters box?

Thank you in advance. hope you understand what im wrote. sorry for bad english.

admin/view/template/catalog/product_list.tpl

```
<td class="text-left"><?php if ($sort == 'p.user_id') { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $sort_user_id; ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($order); ?>"><?php echo "User_ID"; ?></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $sort_user_id; ?>"><?php echo "User_ID"; ?></a>
                <?php } ?></td>
```

admin/model/user/user.php

```
public function getUsers($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "user`";

    $sort_data = array(
        'username',
        'status',
        'date_added'
    );

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY username";
    }

    if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
        $sql .= " DESC";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ASC";
    }

    if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 20;
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

admin/model/catalog/product.php

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, (SELECT keyword FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE query = 'product_id=" . (int)$product_id . "') AS keyword FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

    return $query->row;
}

public function getProducts($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";

    if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
        $sql .= " AND pd.name LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_model'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.model LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_model']) . "%'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_price']) && !is_null($data['filter_price'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.price LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_price']) . "%'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_quantity']) && !is_null($data['filter_quantity'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.quantity = '" . (int)$data['filter_quantity'] . "'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_status']) && !is_null($data['filter_status'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.status = '" . (int)$data['filter_status'] . "'";
    }

    if (isset($data['filter_image']) && !is_null($data['filter_image'])) {
        if ($data['filter_image'] == 1) {
            $sql .= " AND (p.image IS NOT NULL AND p.image <> '' AND p.image <> 'no_image.png')";
        } else {
            $sql .= " AND (p.image IS NULL OR p.image = '' OR p.image = 'no_image.png')";
        }
    }


        if(!$this->user->hasPermission('access', 'extension/module/separate_products') and !$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'localisation/order_status') ){
            $sql .= " AND p.user_id = '" . $this->session->data['user_id'] . "'";
        }

    $sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

    $sort_data = array(
        'pd.name',
        'p.model',
        'p.price',
        'p.quantity',

        'p.user_id',

        'p.status',
        'p.sort_order'
    );

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY pd.name";
    }

    if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
        $sql .= " DESC";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ASC";
    }

    if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 20;
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

admin/controller/catalog/product.php

```
class ControllerCatalogProduct extends Controller {
private $error = array();

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('catalog/product');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $this->getList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where the user_ID came from?
Can you provide product controller (protected function getList() {)?
So I can give you the complete code.

Actually you can use this code to get user details (First name and last name).

```
$this->load->model('user/user');
$user_info = $this->model_user_user->getUser(user_ID);
$data['firstname'] = $user_info['firstname'];
$data['lastname'] = $user_info['lastname'];
```

change the user_ID with the real user_ID data.